# Get link of inner div attribute using dom document and xpath php

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I have following HTML:

```
<div id="unique_id" style="display: none;">   
  <div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="viewLink">
              <div class="viewBuy" onclick="javascript:window.location='https://google.com';return false;">View / Buy</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get onclick atribute value from **div class='viewBuy'** inside **div id='unique_id'**, but getting empty result. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$dataObj = new DOMDocument();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dataObj->loadHtml($HTML);

$idName = 'unique_id';
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dataObj);
$viewAllLink = $xpath->query("//*[@id='$idName')]");

if ($viewAllLink) {
foreach ($viewAllLink as $feeditem) {
        $urlAttribute = $feeditem->getAttribute('onclick');
        if ($urlAttribute) break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` for getting attribute value.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/789848)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='<div id="unique_id" style="display: none;">   
  <div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="viewLink">
              <div class="viewBuy" onclick="javascript:window.location=\'https://google.com\';return false;">View / Buy</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>';
$output=null;

$domdocument= new DOMDocument();
$domdocument->loadXML($string);

$domXpath= new DOMXPath($domdocument);
$result=$domXpath->query('//div[@id="unique_id"]');

$domXpath= new DOMXPath($domdocument);
$result=$domXpath->query('//div[@class="viewBuy"]',$result->item(0));
echo $output =$result->item(0)->getAttribute("onclick");
```

**Output:**
`javascript:window.location='https://google.com';return false;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is I've many divs with **div class="viewBuy"**. so I've to filter it with id first.

Comment: @Ravistm I have updated my post you can check it now.

Comment: What if I've many divs like i edited in my question, sorry i forgot to mention it

Answer (score 0):

@Sahil, thanks for giving multiple answers. I just want to post other 2 answers you gave me, which may be useful for someone else.

**Solution1**

```
$dataObj = new DOMDocument();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dataObj->loadHtml($HTML);

$idName = 'unique_id';
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dataObj);
$viewAllLink = $xpath->query("//div[@id='$idName']/div/div/div/div/div[@class='viewBuy']")->item(0)->getAttribute("onclick");
```

**Solution2**

```
$dataObj = new DOMDocument();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dataObj->loadHtml($HTML);

$idName = 'unique_id';
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dataObj);
$viewAllLink = $xpath->query("//div[@id='$idName')]/div");
getAttribute($viewAllLink);
echo $output;

function getAttribute($result)
{
    global $domdocument,$output;
    if($result->length==1 && empty($result->item(0)->getAttribute("onclick")))
    {
        $domXpath= new DOMXPath($domdocument);
            $result=$domXpath->query('//div[@class="viewBuy"]',$result->item(0));
        getAttribute($result);
    }
    else
    {
        $output = $result->item(0)->getAttribute("onclick");
    }
}
```